# Prompt users to reset their passwords in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, password, accounts

I have a bunch of new users to deploy on our system, and as a part of the initial login I want to give them an opportunity to reset their password. How can I best do this so that we don't have to instruct them specifically to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many users? Where are the passwords stored? How are the passwords distributed?

If you're just creating them in /etc/passwd you can use `passwd --expire`.

```
   The options which apply to the passwd command...

   -e, --expire
       Immediately expire an account´s password. This in effect can force
       a user to change his/her password at the user´s next login.
```

Comment: We created them in /etc/passwd for 100 users. All users are given the same password, and the users are told their username and password orally.

Comment: In a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [chage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chage) to set a users account so it will expire.  I haven't tested but gdm is supposed to notify the user to change their password.

Answer (score 0):

looking to man page of chage - change user password expiry information
it has example!